# unable to install gatsby-plugin-transition-link with npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, gatsby

[image]

Error report

I am unable to resolve this issue. I have spent hours looking for a solution. I can't find one. Please help. I know it's similar to the question [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjHiqOOhp_wAhXl4jgGHd4rC-AQFjAEegQIDxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F66695868%2Fim-not-able-to-install-gatsby-plugin-transition-link-with-npm&usg=AOvVaw1QUtY0PRko4QqE-DVixUjV). But there is no method to solve there. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is quite self-explanatory. You are running React on a version greater than  `17.0.1` (`^17.0.1`), specifically the `17.0.2` and the dependency (`gatsby-plugin-transition-link`) needs the `16.8.5`.

If downgrading React's version is not an option, you may need to review the [migration guide (from `v2` to `v3`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/) to install peer-dependencies, as some [GitHub threads suggests](https://github.com/TylerBarnes/gatsby-plugin-transition-link/issues/264).

Check your outdated dependencies with:

```
npm outdated
```

In addition, update your `npm`  version to the lastest one by:

```
npm install -g npm
```